# Angular2: Recursion with Callbacks and REST api calls

Tags: http, angular, recursion, callback, synchronization

I'm doing the following process in order try and optimize speed and load on the server. However, things start to get done out of order and I'm not sure why. Which leads me to believe something is going on that I don't understand. Here is the code:

```
getInfo ( startIndex, endIndex ) { //starts with 0, 3 as the two params
    var arr = globalArray.splice(startIndex, endIndex);
    var tempThis = this;
    this.function1( arr, function () {
        this.function2( arr, function () {
            if (end != tempThis.globalArray.length - 1) {
                var newStart = endIndex;
                var newEnd = endIndex + 3;
                if (newEnd > tempThis.globalArray.length - 1) {
                    newEnd = tempThis.globalArray.length - 1;
                }
                console.log("about to recurse");
                tempThis.getInfo(newStart, newEnd);
            }
        })
    }) 

}

function1 ( list ) {
    list.forEach( function ( thing ) {
        httpCall( params, function ( data, error ) {
            //logic
            if(list.indexOf(thing) == list.length - 1) {
                callback();
            }
        })
    })
}

function2 ( list ) {
    list.forEach( function ( thing ) {
        httpCall( params, function ( data, error ) {
            //logic
            if(list.indexOf(thing) == list.length - 1) {
                callback();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

The intention of this process is to get everything sequential. So, I have a large globalList that I want to do logic on. I break it up 3 at a time and send through my logic. It does function1 things, and then (and only then) when I find that I am on the last index of the mini list I call the call back and it should move to function2 logic. Then and only then should it increment the indexes and recurse.

My understanding with callbacks is that it should basically make the processes synchronous. However, the callbacks are being called in an unpredictable order and often too many times. I feel like my logic in function1 and 2 are sound.

**Question**: Is my understanding wrong? If not what about this process is not good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside of your function1/function2 forEach will be processed in an asynchronous way because HTTP calls are asynchronous. This means that if your smaller list passed to the function has 3 items, 3 HTTP calls will be fired off and handled at different times. There is no guarantee that the calls will complete in the order that you made the requests, so you will have situations where the last of the 3 calls made is completed before the other 2 have completed and the callback will be fired before the other two have completed. You can try to solve that problem by keeping track of how many have been processed so far instead of simply looking at the index.

```js
function processPart1(list, callback) {
    let numProcessed = 0;

    list.forEach(function (item) {
        httpCall(params, function (data, error) {
            //logic

            numProcessed++;

            if (numProcessed === list.length) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

A problem that you will find with this approach of passing callbacks around and trying to manage making an asynchronous process behave synchronously is that it can get hard to read and bugs like this can creep in. Switching over to a promise-based technique can help out with both of these. Promise libraries like Q have features to help out with both of these. For example, Q has a method to process a list of asynchronous actions and do work once all have been completed (i.e. Q.all).

Additionally, the code being called does not need to know about what the code calling it needs to do once it is finished. Promises seem to be one of the best practices to solve the problems that come up because of the nature of asynchronous programming. Many libraries now include a promise-based approach to HTTP calls (i.e. jQuery).

Using a library like Q, you could do something similar to the following. This is just an example to show you how things could potentially be done using promises to orchestrate everything.

```js
function getInfo(startIndex, endIndex) { //starts with 0, 3 as the two params
    var arr = globalArray.splice(startIndex, endIndex);
    var tempThis = this;

    Q.all(arr.map(function (item) {
        return processItemPart1(item));
    }))
    .then(function () { // this is called when all part 1 promises resolve
        return Q.all(arr.map(function (item) {
            return processItemPart2(item);
        }));
    })
    .then(function () { // this is called when all part 2 promises resolve
        if (end != tempThis.globalArray.length - 1) {
            var newStart = endIndex;
            var newEnd = endIndex + 3;
            if (newEnd > tempThis.globalArray.length - 1) {
                newEnd = tempThis.globalArray.length - 1;
            }
            console.log("about to recurse");
            tempThis.getInfo(newStart, newEnd);
        }
    })
    .fail(function () { // this is called when an error occurs
        // do anything on error
    })
    .done();
}

function processItemPart1(item) {
    // This is one way using the library to make the HTTP call
    // promise-based.
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        httpCall(params, function (data, error) {
            if (error) {
                // logic for error
                reject(new Error(error));
                return;
            }

            // logic for success
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

function processItemPart2(item) {
    // This is another way using the library to make the HTTP call
    // promise-based.
    let deferred = Q.defer();

    httpCall(params, function (data, error) {
        if (error) {
            // logic for error
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));

            return;
        }

        // logic for success
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

function processItemPart3IfThereWasOne(item) {
    // This is another way using the Q library with a library like jQuery
    // whose ajax calls actually return a promise.
    return Q($.ajax(params))
    .then(function () {
        // logic
    });
}
```

**Resources:**

Q Library Documentation: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem right now. Callbacks are by definition asynchronous, and the http client returns observables which where designed to manage data asynchronously.

I am looking into `ngrx` right now which can solve this issue by managing a "stream" of actions (aka - sequence of commands over time) to more seamlessly transition between states that the data would be in.